# Check if HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["filex"] has file

Tags: asp.net, forms, request

I am working on an ASP .net webpage which receives a form which is posted to it. The posted form has three as well.

```
filename = uploadFile(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file1"], path);
```

This is the code through which i upload a file to my server. And this is the code of the function.

```
public string uploadFile(HttpPostedFile file, string dest)
    {
        string filename = file.FileName;
        string path = Server.MapPath(dest);
        String extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        filename = filename.Replace(extension, "");
        filename = filename.Replace(".", "");
        filename = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + filename + extension;
        string savepath = path + "/" + filename;
        file.SaveAs(savepath);
        return filename;
    }
```

The problem is I am not able to check if file1 from the posted form actually has file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FileUpload control in conjunction with the HasFile property:

[FileUpload.HasFile Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you have to do it that way, you can simply check if the [ContentLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) is greater than zero.